# Handling time variables in R for ANOVA

Tags: r, time, lubridate

im relatively new to R. I´m doing an experiment where i measure the exact time where a couple of insects mate in 14 days in different luminic conditions (12:12H Light/Dark, Continious light, Continious dark).The idea is to analyze this data with ANOVA, but i'm having problems with the data. So I have a .csv file with 3 columns: Light condition, Date and Time. Date is not required for the analysis so i dont need it. But i have trouble converting the time data for a proper data R can work with. I've already tried `read.csv(file="",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` but it doesnt work at all, I've also tried with `lubridate` , `as.POSIX` function and `strptime()` but nothing seems to work (or maybe im not converting the data at all for a proper analysis)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you read the data in R? Can you post `dput(head(df))` where `df` is your dataframe.

Comment: I did, here it goes `'data.frame': 173 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Nivel: Factor w/ 3 levels "DD","LD","LL": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Dia  : Factor w/ 54 levels "2016-07-07","2016-07-08",..: 1 2 4 5 6 8 9 1 1 4 ...
 $ Hora : Factor w/ 151 levels "0:01","0:02",..: 79 129 4 95 84 133 37 60 52 29 ...` @RonakShah

Comment: Also `structure(list(Nivel = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("DD", 
"LD", "LL"), class = "factor"), Dia = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 8L), .Label = c("2016-07-07",...` and so on with dates `class = "factor"), Hora = structure(c(79L, 129L, 
4L, 95L, 84L, 133L), .Label = c("0:01", "0:02" ...`, and so on with time `class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have date and time in two different columns and for time you have only hour and minutes. You can combine them using `paste` and convert to date time using appropriate `format`.

```
df$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(paste(df$Dia, df$Hora),
                         format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",tz = "UTC")
#Can also use strptime
df$DateTime <- strptime(paste(df$Dia, df$Hora), 
                       format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "UTC")
```

Or with `lubridate`

```
df$DateTime <- lubridate::ymd_hm(paste(df$Dia, df$Hora))
```

Comment: With the three methods, it gives me the same error

`Error in df$Dia : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable `

Comment: @AgustínLovrich Is your dataframe called `df`? Do they have columns with names `Dia` and `Hora`? Please update your post with exact output of `dput(head(df))` which we can copy-paste into our R session.

Comment: Oh silly me! No, my dataframe is called `copulas` Now I replaced `df` for `copulas` and  works fine. About the other question, my dataframe have columns with names `Dia` and `Hora`. From here how can I use this new column `DateTime` for the ANOVA and check assumptions